# What can I do with all these ingots?

Tags: dungeons-of-dredmor

I chose the Blacksmith skill in Dungeons of Dredmor and now have a bunch of ingots.  I already have good equipment, so what I can do with all these extra ingots?  Is it better to sell them as-is or crafted into items?

Comment: Whatcha gunna do with all that junk?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ingots have limited uses outside of forging. They can be:

- Ground with an Elven Grinder, to make ingredients for potions,
- Sold to Brax,
- Transformed into lutefisk with the Hodaric cube.

If you chose to transform then, you should rather make something like bolt from them, in order to obtain more lutefisk from one ingot.

**Edit:**
If you want to sell them, you should before try to craft them into something more valuable, depending on the ingot type:

- Plastic into plastic ring,
- Copper and tin should be made into bronze then a dagger or gladius, if you don't have enough tin, make a cooper ring,
- With iron, try to make steel then a steel cuirass or even a full plate armor if you have enough,
- With aluminum, also try to make a cuirass,
- Zinc, brass, silver, gold, electrum and platinum are good sold directly.

There may be better deal with cross-metal crafting, but this is what I found for direct metal crafting.

Comment: Is it better sold to Brax as ingots? or is more convenient craft something and sell the result to Brax?

Comment: Hmm, after a quick look on the wiki, I'd say its always more profitable to craft something out of the ingot before selling it. Gonna look it up more and edit my answer.

Comment: What kind "are better sold as-is," ? Looks like the sentence is lacking something or is it my english :(

Comment: my bad, moved a bit of text and forget to remove the part it left behind

Answer (score 1):

Some ingots also are used in crafting for items only in their raw form. Cassiterite, Hemetite, Malachite, and Zincblende are the four "rocks" that can be crafted directly with other items to make a magic item (as well as forged into ingots for additional crafting instead.)